# How to avoid gcloud compute alerting store the key in cache

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I wrote some small code for controlling multiple compute engine on google cloud platform. The whole file is here in [github](https://github.com/MichaelKHTai/BulksGCEController).

The part causes problem is `gcloud compute ssh` in the following

```
def upload_file(self, projectname):
    var = raw_input("Upload file with name: " + projectname + " will remove all file and directory with same name in the instance. Are you sure? (y/n)")
    if var.lower().strip() != "y":
        print "Abort uploading."
        return
    is_zip = False
    if projectname.split('.')[1] == "zip":
        is_zip = True
    fullpath_projectname = __location__ + "/" + projectname
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath_projectname):
        all_instances = self.search_any('instances', filter="labels.type=" + self.working_group_label)
        all_instances_name = [x['name'] for x in all_instances]


        i = 0
        for instance in all_instances_name:

            temp_command = 'gcloud_command_' + str(i) 
            i += 1
            temp_instance = user_name + "@" + instance
            temp_file_path = '/home/' + user_name + '/'

            command_arr = []
            command_arr.append('call gcloud compute ssh ' + temp_instance + ' --zone ' + zone + ' --command "cd ' + temp_file_path + '; sudo rm -rf ' + temp_file_path + projectname.split('.')[0] + '; sudo rm -f ' + temp_file_path + projectname.split('.')[0] + '*"\n')
            command_arr.append('call gcloud compute scp "' + fullpath_projectname + '" ' + temp_instance + ':' + temp_file_path + '\n')
            if is_zip:
                command_arr.append('call gcloud compute ssh ' + temp_instance + ' --zone ' + zone + ' ' + ' --command "cd ' + temp_file_path + '; sudo unzip ' + temp_file_path + projectname + '"' + '\n')
            with open(os.path.join(__location__, 'bat/' + temp_command + '.bat'), 'w') as bat:
                bat.writelines(command_arr)
            subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(__location__, 'bat/' + temp_command + '.bat'), shell=True)
```

This part is for uploading the same file (usually .zip) to all instances with same tag. However doing it on my local computer will jump out a lot of alert asking me for saving the ssh fingerprint.

Like this,

[image: Alert]

Originally it is a small tool for my own convenience, in order to run multiple compute engine to query online data (I want to have multiple IP so as to avoid being classified as DDoS). But now I need to share this with other teams so that bundle of alert causes other's confusing.

I can cache it one by one manually, but it is not convenient for others.

I tried to answer the caching by changing last line

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(__location__, 'bat/' + temp_command + '.bat'), shell=True)
proc.communicate(input='y')
```

But **this make all upload just do one by one** and that's extremely slow for many instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning comes from the underlying ssh binary. You can use `--ssh-flag` and `--scp-flag` to `gcloud compote ssh` and `gcloud compute scp` respectively to control the behavior of the underlying binary actually doing the ssh operations.

A good explanation of the possible ways to do so is [provided here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110557/force-ssh-to-not-to-print-warnings) (look at the first option in the accepted answer). However, I don't know if PuTTY's will accept the same syntax, so you might have to look for the proper flag value for it.

The complete docs for these commands are available [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp).

Comment: That's not related to `--ssh-flag` I think, what arg should I put for this flag? By the way, the link you provided do solve my problem, but you should edit your answer for putting back the `-q` command, it will be easier for reading.

Comment: You mean a complete example? Happy to edit, just want to see if I understand it correctly :)